# tcpdump display packets with high delay

Tags: linux, tcpdump

I used tcpdump to capture packets from local rsyslog service to syslog server, however, when I tried different commands (with/without dst option) in tcpdump, the displayed result has a delay.

**Expected/Desired Behavior:**

```bash
tcpdump -n -e -i any -A | grep hello               # without dst option
tcpdump -n -e -i any dst 10.8.8.3 -A | grep hello  # with dst option
```

The above two commands should display the packets simultaneously or with very short delay.

**Actual Behavior:**
Command with dst option `tcpdump -n -e -i any dst 10.8.8.3 -A | grep hello` display the packet with a delay of up to 20 secs, which makes me mistakenly think that the packet is not sent successfully.
[image]

> command1 captures the packet immediately

[image]

> command2 cannot capture the packet immediately. After about 20 seconds, the packet finally display on the screen.

**Additional Infomation:**

- Debian 4.9.189-3+deb9u2 (2019-11-11) x86_64 GNU/Linux
- tcpdump version 4.9.3
- libpcap version 1.8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`tcpdump(8)`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/tcpdump/tcpdump.8#l) (choosing slightly older than OP's version, but any newer would do):

> `-l`
>
> Make stdout line buffered. Useful if you want to see the data while capturing it. E.g.,
>
> ```
> tcpdump -l | tee dat
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> tcpdump -l > dat & tail -f dat
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> `-U` is similar to `-l` in its behavior, but it will cause output to be ``packet-buffered'', [...]

So just add `-l` to `tcpdump` whenever you need "real time" display.